# Skip controller loading in url for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Hi i was wondering if it's possible to bypass the standard methods that codeigniter has when loading controllers, methods.

As for example, when i browse to domain.com/folder/ i want to go to my project folder given in the url and not codeigniter to try to load a controller/method (or just index method).

Why do i need this? It's simply because have installed awstats to my site and i need codeigniter not to try to access a "stats controller" for /stats/

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

> As for example, when i browse to domain.com/folder/ i want to go to my project folder given in the url and not codeigniter to try to load a controller/method (or just index method).

Check `.htaccess` file of your project - it basically routes all invocation through router file (i.e. `index.php`) but you can easily add more rules to your `.htaccess` to exclude certain directories or files. I.e. adding this line prior other rules should exclude "stats" folder.

```
RewriteRule ^(stats)($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage with routes file.

```
projectfolder/application/config/routes.php
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't that for routes that i want together with logic around them? If no, how do i add skipping logic in routes.php ?